# How can I enable CascadeMode.Stop from FluentValidation throug IoC on ASP.NET Core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I've seen it somewhere but couldn't find it anymore. Something like the following:

```cs
public class Startup {

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

services.AddControllers()
                .AddFluentValidation(s =>
                {   
                    s.ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode.Stop;                    
                    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be:

```
ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Response from JeremySkinner the library maintainer:

Either:

```cs
using FluentValidation;
```

```cs
services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => {
  fv.ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;
});
```

Or just:

```cs
ValidatorOptions.Global.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;
```

Both have the same result (they're the same configuration instance)